# How remove spacebar in string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
SELECT '17, 18' STRING_ 
    FROM DUAL;
```

remove spacebar

Comment: You can use `REPLACE`. Something like `SELECT REPLACE ('1 2',' ', '')`

Comment: You found out how to remove the "." from a string in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286889/how-search-one-symbol-in-string-in-oracle. You can use the same mechanism for removing space.

Comment: Sorry. This do not work.

Comment: [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

i assume you want to remove the space

```
SELECT replace('17, 18',' ','') STRING_ 
    FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Sorry. This do not work.

Comment: Sorry. I mistake. Good . This works.

Answer (score 1):

Using **TRANSLATE**:

```
SQL> SELECT translate('17, 18', '# ', '#') STRING_
  2      FROM DUAL;

STRIN
-----
17,18

SQL>
```

Using **REPLACE**:

```
SQL> SELECT replace('17, 18', ' ', '') STRING_
  2      FROM DUAL;

STRIN
-----
17,18
```

In Oracle, `''` is treated as `NULL` value.

Comment: @TatianaBancu Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: select regexp_replace('17, 18','/s','') from dual;